# Problem that clone project cannot be run due to gitignore

Tags: spring, git, ignore

I'm using gitignore, and I'm good at push and pull for personal management.

The focus is on my own creation, so I have all the configuration files, so it runs well locally.

However, if I "Clone" this project and download it to an empty folder, it cannot be run anywhere.

It seems as if there is no configuration file necessary for project configuration or server execution.

I am attaching my gitignore.

Is this what gitignore originally intended?

I want to clone a project so that it can run.
Do I have to delete gitignore to do that?

p.s If I delete gitignore and clone all projects (including build artifacts) it works fine.

use tool & etc : Intellij, Spring, Tomcat

```
### Java template
*.class
 
# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
 
### macOS template
*.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride
 
# IntelliJ project files
.idea
.idea/*.xml
*.iml
out
gen
build
rebel.xml
 
# Compliled files
/target/
**/target
 
/example/
 
# Gradle
.gradle
/build/
.gradletasknamecache
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you don't distribute compiled binaries with your git repo. The convention is to either have users compile the code locally, or distribute that code using a package management system like Maven, Ivy, npm, Nuget, pip or gem. This isn't a hard and fast rule however.